# MouseEvent on ImageIcon

Tags: java, jframe, mouseevent, netbeans-7

How to move ImageIcons placed on Jlabel from one panel to another.A chess board with panels is created in JFrame, and want to move the piece images from one panel to another using MouseMotionListner or MouseListner.

Comment: Try to update your question with an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/). Show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

- Add a MouseListener to the JLabel
- One possibility is to use drag-and-drop by going through the tutorial on this.
- Or you could do your own drag and drop:
- kick up the JLabel to the glass pane on mousePressed
- Drag it on the glass pane
- deposit it on the JPanel that it is hovering over on mouseReleased.